# Passing get parameters to url

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```
<li v-for='category in categoriesData' :key='category.seoName'>
    <label class='custom-checkbox'>
        <input type='checkbox' :value='category.id' v-model='checkedCategories' @click='request()'>
        <span>{{ category.title }}</span>
    </label>
</li>
```

There is a component with `checkboxes`, when clicked, it calls a function that sends an `axios request`. How can I add get parameters to the url without reloading the page?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue you can use `fullPath` like mentioned below in `request()` method.

```
this.$router.push({path: this.$route.fullPath, query: {param: 'paramvalue} });
```

Comment: Unfortunately ```vue router``` is not used in the project. But I tried this and it worked =>             ```if (history.pushState) {
              const newUrl = response.request.responseURL;
              history.pushState(null, null, newUrl);
            }```